# java lombok bean validation

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, lombok

I have below code, where I marked the text field as `@NotNull`, and I tried to create object by passing `null` value into that field.

I don't see the validation works. The program completes successfully with the value for text as `null`

Can I please know what I am missing here and why no exception is thrown while creating the object?

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class testInput {

    private int id;

    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "text not be null")
    private String text;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Starting");
        testInput inp = new testInput(1,null);
        System.out.println("Ending");

    }

}
```

Comment: Please, use `CamelCase` for naming your classes and interfaces. Also, which version of `Lombok` you're using? how do you run the program? in the IDE or outside of it?

Comment: `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` does not get validated by your standard JVM (whether or not aided by lombok). You need to bootstrap a bean-validation implementation and its validation methods need to be called (explicitly by you or by your environment, such as an application server/container). And lombok's `@NonNull` is a different thing, but the fact that you're expecting lombok's implementation of `@AllArgsConstructor` to enforce your bean-validation's `@NotNull` says that you're mixing things up. Rather start by reading up on the specification and on lombok's workings.

Comment: @Giorgi Tsiklauri i run in m IDE Intellij. Lombokv1.18.10

Comment: @ernest_k thank you, makes more sense. I was in an assumption it will be auto triggered. Let me go through the document and see how enforce validation

Comment: @joe, Yes that what i'm looking for thank you. make my work simple

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lombok's [`NonNull`](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull). If a *null* is passed as an argument, it will throw a `NullPointerException`, without associating a validator to your code.

```java
import lombok.NonNull;

@NonNull
private String text;
```